# NHibernate Schema Generation

Tags: nhibernate, database-design, orm

Could you please share your experience with NHibernate schema generation? How much scalable it is in terms of complexity and size of the data model? Does it have any major performance implication compared to hand crafted data model?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about generating the database schema from class definitions?  Versus crafting the database schema manually to match the class definitions?  If that is the case, it's probably an 80% solution and pretty close to what you need for a first release.  After a first production release, you have to think about migrations which the schema generation doesn't really do.

Comment: Yes Michale, I am referring to generating db schema from class definitions. Good to know that it is pretty close to version 1 needs, I think it will save lots of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it immensely useful for development, when you can use it with a bit of code to rebuild and repopulate test databases at will. Michael's point about migrations matches our experience - once you've made the initial release you'll need to decide on another method for altering production databases.

FWIW, we've used NH schema generation with about 30 models of the usual kinds (including a table per subclass arrangement), and the definitions that it generates are correct, so there's no obvious limit to the size of the schema that it could handle.

I now tend to think that an automatically generated schema is almost always a better starting point than a hand-crafted one, because the software will give you something that is totally consistent and exactly what you specified. The kinds of optimizations that a skilled DBA can do aren't likely to be necessary or useful until after you have a large, specific workload to tune for.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to export your schema and populate your database, you would like to see the Fluent NHibernate Schema Tool. It is capable to read your assemblies, hibernate.cfg.xml, *.hbm.xml and Fluent Mappings. You can generate/execute the DDL of your database (create/update/drop tables) and it accepts a CSV-like input file to be used for populating the created/updated database (the dataset file accepts small queries to be done in HQL). This tool is very useful for unit testing and Web applications that use NHibernate.

See more: https://bitbucket.org/guibv/fnst/wiki/Home.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Apples and Pears. Hand crafted model will always (well **should**) out perform any ORM technology.

I personally think NHibernate performs well and will map virtually any OO model to a relational model, that's the beauty of it. There are a few gotcha's like being aware of application start up time and making sure you are using session management correctly.

I would recommend NHibernate and have been using it for 18 months now on schemas that hold around 80 tables or so and have not yet seen any major issues.

Comment: Good to know that it is working well for 80 tables and 18 months. I know hand crafted DB models are going to be better, thats why I mentioned if there are any 'major performance implications'.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there aren't any performance implications. In fact aren't there many options how to create the tables to fit the mapping files. There are some additional features just for schema creation, like the possibility to specify database data types, create constraints and indexes as well as running arbitrary sql when creating the schema.

Performance tuning can usually be done after automatically creating the schema. For instance, you let NH create the tables and run some `Alter Table` statements to set some performance relevant settings. It is also very easy to create (or replace) indexes afterwards. All this could even be written to the mapping files. The hard work is still done by NH: creating all the tables and columns according to the information that is already there: the mapping files.